# Can't read any CD or DVD in Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, mount, dvd, cd

I can't mount any CD or DVD on Ubuntu Gnome.

I tried to run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

but it wasn't successfully.

Here is output after `sudo lshw -C disk`:

```
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST9500420AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0006
       serial: 5VJ40L7T
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000c0194
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: CDDVDW TS-L633N
       vendor: hp
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 0300
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

after `mount` next output:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /usr type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=nazar)
```

Here is output after `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=69afa331-a4f0-46b9-af27-d3fdaa741653 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=df65147d-afbc-495a-ab0f-80ef47415f4e /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /usr was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c8454fa0-7359-40d6-a007-db672e61c114 /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=89661f0a-71d8-4f24-a9e5-b9d3c094cc3c none            swap    sw              0       0
# cdrom 0
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/  auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
# cdrom 1
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/ auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mount -a`, use the proper command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/$USER/<mountpoint>
```

... replacing `<mountpoint>` with the name of a real directory in `/media/<username>` where `<username>` is the all-lowercase name of the user account.